# MemoryStream upload to Minio results in size 0

Tags: c#, .net, stream, memorystream, minio

I am trying to copy data selectively from one Minio server to another with a c# windows application. 
Data is downloaded OK, no exceptions occur, but file size in destination server is zero.
A little bit simplified, my source code is something as follows:

```
await source_client.GetObjectAsync("bucket", "path/from/file", async (stream) =>
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        await destintation_client.PutObjectAsync("bucket", "path/to/file", memoryStream,  memoryStream.Length);
    }

});
```

I use the MemoryStream to buffer all data downloaded from source server in memory before uploading it to destination server.
I have checked with a breakpoint that data is downloaded correctly and that memoryStream.Length is not zero.
Both servers are tested and work correctly.
However, after the process, I see that destination server has the desired number of files, but all with zero size.

Comment: Hi, I have landed in the same situation. Unable to find any solution. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder. I could't get to work `CopyToAsync`, however it works OK with the sychronous version `CopyTo`.
It appears not being properly awaited....